# php header('Location: http://example.com') does not pass the referrer

Tags: php, header, referer

**Problem:**

While redirecting user from http://sample.com to http://example.com via `header('Location: http://example.com')` - `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` is empty.

Even after setting referer via `header('Referer: http://sample.com')` and then redirecting via  `header('Location: http://example.com')` - `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` is still empty.

**Expected outcome:**

http://example.com receives `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` with appropriate referrer on redirection via `header('Location: http://example.com')`

**Use case**

- User receives unique invite link via email pointing to http://sample.com
- User clicks link and is redirected to http://sample.com/?i=123456
- http://sample.com validate invite and if it's still valid(i.e. unused) redirects user to http://example.com/?i=123456
- http://example.com does not have ability to validate invitation, thus it's important to know if user was redirected from the right source

**Other:**

- behavior is correct if user cliks a link on http://sample.com
- behavior is correct if user is redirected via javascript `window.location="http://example.com"
- $_GET is not an option as it can be very easily forged since http://example.com can't validate invitation

Comment: HTTP_REFERRER seems to be informed by the browser. It might work in Chrome but not on Firefox and vice-versa, it's just not trustworthy, since it's not standartized.

Comment: any proposals how to achieve it with and ensure cross-browser compatibility?

Comment: Can I ask what you need that header for? As the answer below states, this header is not trust worthy and doesn't always exist.

Comment: Perhaps redirect with a $_GET?

Comment: The only information you can be sure to receive "on the other side" is whatever information you put into that `Location:` header. So, yes, add some identifying information into the URL itself.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP Doc [Server Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> 'HTTP_REFERER' The address of the page (if any) which referred the
>   user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all
>   user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify
>   HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

You might be better off setting the current url in a Cookie or Session and using that.

Comment: well, cookie is the right thing to do if you are able to centralize it. in cross-domain case where some of those domains may be out of your control it will be impossible